# The size of Lindelof space

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, gn.general-topology

**Question.** Suppose that $X$ is a Lindelof space such
that every point of $X$ is a $G_{\delta}$-point. Then is it true that $|X| ≤ 2^{\omega}$?

Answer (score 10):

There are  consistency results due to Shelah and Gorelic for the negative answer. Shelah has proved the consistency of $GCH+$there exists a Lindelof space with points $G_\delta$ of size $\aleph_2.$ See Shelah's paper ''On  some  problems  in  general  topology''. Gorelic has extended this result to get $CH+2^{\aleph_1}$ arbitrary large+ there is such a space of size $2^{\aleph_1}$.

It is also consistent with $GCH$ that there exists a Lindelof space with points $G_\delta$ of size $\aleph_\omega.$ See R. Knight's paper ''A topological application of flat morasses'', Fundamenta Mathematicae, 194 (2007) pp. 45-66.

On the other hand Shelah has proved the consistency of $CH+$ there is no Lindelof space with points $G_\delta$  of size $\aleph_2.$ See Shelah's paper ''On  some  problems  in  general  topology''.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the construction of a Lindelöf point $G_\delta$ space of size $\aleph_\omega$ in "A topological application of flat morasses" contains an error which seems to be  incorrigible.

Comment: This seems to be a comment on Mohammad Golshani's answer, yes? Would you like to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Would you please say which part of the argument is wrong?

Comment: For reference, Knight's paper is but a click away: http://journals.impan.pl/cgi-bin/doi?fm194-1-3

Answer (score 2):

The consistency of this statement is Problem 1 in [these slides](http://settheory.mathtalks.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/viennafinal.pdf) by F. Tall, where the problem is attributed to Arhangelski. Some partial results already mentioned in Mohammad Golshani´s answer are given. The following is also mentioned:

> Theorem (Tall-Usuba): Lévy-collapse a weak compact and then add $\aleph_3$ Cohen subsets of $\omega_1$. Then there are no counterexamples of size $\aleph_2$, even relaxing "points $G_\delta$" to "pseudocharacter $\leq \aleph_1$".